# Marketing Cloud: How to send subscriber key to landing page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I created a landing page in marketing cloud and after publishing I got an address like http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/someidstuff
Now I want to use this address as hyperlink in an email and need some kind of identification of the recipient. This should be the subscriberkey, or not...? How can I add the subscriberkey to this kind of hyperlink? I tried with &key=%%_subscriberkey%%, but got an server error.
Any hints?

Thanks a lot and kind regards
Stefan

Comment: What would you like to achieve? For authentication, it's better to use Microsites instead of landingpages.

Comment: This question might be stupid, but what in detail is a microsite? I built this landing page over the "Web" -> "Cloud Pages" funcionalty. The problem is, that we don't want to use the "original" MC landing page as we can't use custom content there. That's why we try to push an identifier from an email to this page.

Comment: More info on Microsites: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://http://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/someidstuff?key=%%_subscriberkey%%">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: This may answer the question, but it is hard to tell because you have not included any explanation. Markup only answers (especially when one line) are generally lower quality and tend to get flagged for deletion. Please add a little explanation here.

Comment: That's fine delete it. I didn't think showing how adding a personalization string as a querystring parameter needed explanation.

Comment: I'm not saying I want to delete it. I'm explaining why I did not vote to delete. I'm trying to help you be a better community member. Bit of a disappointing reaction. I don't have a lot of insight into the functionality but a good answer would help the uneducated in addition to SMEs.

Comment: Thanks Victor, this was helpfull. I'll be back soon with new questions, I'm sure ;-)